# unable to use location keyword in cloudera quickstart VM

Tags: hadoop, hive

help me on the below issue.

when i tried to create a new table in hive with location keyword i  am getting the below error. please help me

```
hive> create table employee2(empid int, empname string)
    > row format delimited                             
    > fields terminated by ' '                         
    > stored as textfile                               
    > location '/home/cloudera/Desktop/Hive';          
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:4828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:4802)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3075)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1748)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1746)
)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask``
```

Thanks,
Anbu k.

Answer (score 0):

The user you are running hive dont have access to metastore .. in your stacktrace its given with `drwxr-xr-x`, quick solution is to run your hive with `root`

Comment: can please you say the steps ?